# Threaded SocketServer not receiving second message

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to implement a simple threaded SocketServer (using SocketServer.ThreadedMixIn). However, my server stops receiving further messages. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import SocketServer
import sys

class MYAgentHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            print "Received request " + str(data) + "\n"
            reply = str(agent.processAgentMessage(data))
            self.request.send(reply)
            self.request.close()
        except Exception, instr:
            print "While processing data " + data + " error encountered " + str(instr) + "\n"

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    allow_reuse_address = True
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)

class MYAgent:
    def processAgentMessage(self, msg):
        try:
            tokens = msg.split('^')
            if tokens[0] == "CreateSession":
                return("New session")
            elif tokens[0] == "GetStatus":
                return("Init")
        except Exception, instr:
            print "Error while processing message " + str(instr) + "\n"

agent = MYAgent()

def main():
    MYServer = sys.argv[1]
    MYAgentPort = sys.argv[2]
    agent.listener = ThreadedTCPServer((MYServer, int(MYAgentPort)), MYAgentHandler)
    agent.listener.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is my client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import socket
import time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('localhost', 15222))
    try:
        sock.send("CreateSession")
        sessionID = str(sock.recv(1024))
        print "Received: " + sessionID
        sock.send("GetStatus^"+sessionID)
        print "Sent Getstatus\n"
        time.sleep(1)
        response = str(sock.recv(1024))
        print "status of " + str(sessionID) + " is " + str(response) + "\n"
        sock.close()
    except Exception, instr:
        print "Error occurred " + str(instr) + "\n"
```

Here is one session. Server output:

```
$ ./t.py localhost 15222
Received request CreateSession
```

Client output:

```
$ ./client.py
Received: New session
Sent Getstatus

status of New session is

$
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `self.request.close()` You clearly close the connection after receiveing first message.

Comment: I lifted the code from an example. I have tried without closing as well, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, because you read only once. Remove `self.request.close()` and wrap entire method with `while True:` loop.

Comment: You are right it worked, thank you very much. I was under the impression that the handle method is called every time a message is received. Muddled thinking :(.

Comment: Handle method is called only once (when connection is established). I'm glad it works, you can accept it as an answer. ;)

Comment: How do I accept it as an answer. I am unable to vote as I am not credible enough.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `self.request.close()` (which closes the connection) and wrap everything with `while True:` (so it will continue to read from the same socket).